# I cant acess my HDD

Tags: hard-drive, live-cd

First of all, I'm a total Linux noob. I was running the latest version of Ubuntu but eventually I wasn't able to boot no more, the Ubuntu logo appeared and then it was only a blinking white bar indefinitely, without charging.

Now, my problem is the following. I want to do a fresh install and I am trying to recover my latest files from the HDD using the Ubuntu live CD. I click on the HDD and obtain the following

[image]

I honestly don't really know whats going on. Looking at disks I have this...

[image]

Can anyone help me out?  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing pretty well for a self-described "noob." 
That error message just means Ubuntu can't read or mount the filesystem at /dev/sda1 for some reason. But it does see the disk and the partitions, so the disk hardware is running at least partly.
"read" means understand whats there 
"mount" means connect it to a specific directory ( "mount point") so you can use the files.

If that drive partition, /dev/sda1. won't mount, you are screwed. But lets try to fix it... Go to a command line as root on your livecd.

```
$ whoami
some-ordinary-user

# whoami
root

$ "sudo su -"  to get to root
```

Try the e2fsck  fix the drive command:

```
# e2fsck -p /dev/sda1
```

If you encounter errors, post them.

added below in an edit

So you are mounted. To test whats there:

```
# mount
```

This will tell you the mount point, a directory.

```
# cd <the path>/mountpoint
# find . -type f
# ls -la *
```

also useful

```
# df -h
# locate <some string you expect to be in a directory or filename>
```

**PS**...   for command line messages just do a cut&paste instead of a bitmap.

Comment: I have done that and this is what I get.  [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/e0kj5z.png[/IMG]  The error when I try to open the HDD has changed, I can access the home folder but it is empty.  [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/ztu6pl.png[/IMG]